# JS: Is there a way to tell what object called a function?

Tags: javascript

In a function is there a way to get a reference to the object that called it? I have the same instance of a Flash object on the page twice, each one can make calls to JS through ExternalInterface, I cannot code the Flash objects to each pass a different ID because it is 2 instances of the same Flash object, so it there a way for JS to get a reference to which one called the function?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can't you pass an ID to the Flash object when you instantiate it? (via a query string or params). Then you could use that ID in your JavaScript function calls.

Comment: Let me know if it works. I've only ever done a tiny bit of Flash.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know about ExternalInterface but have you tried examine the `this` object during the execution of your function?

Of course you could always use a closure.  Ultimately you have to give the Flash object a function to be executed.  For example I have `myObj1` and `myObj2` that take a callback method `fnCallback` but for some reason does not set the `this` context when executing this functions to themselves.  Hence I can do this:-

```
function setCallback(obj, fn)
{
  obj.callback = function() {fn.apply(obj, arguments);}
}

setCallback(myObj1, fnCallback);
setCallback(myObj2, fnCallback);
```

Now I can code fnCallback using `this` as a reference to the specific object that is calling the function.

Comment: I am not exactly sure what you mean, can you please elaborate a little more? Are you saying that "this" inside the JS function refers to the flash object that called the function? Thanks.

Comment: Any object can be provided to a function execution as the 'this' context,  I'm not sure this applies in this case since I've no direct experience with ExternalInterface, my suggestion is that you simply give it a go.

Answer (score 0):

[arguments.caller](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Functions_and_function_scope/arguments/caller) or [Function.caller](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Global_Objects/Function/caller) but you might want to look at reorganizing your code to avoid using them. There really is another way to get what you want -- I guarantee it.

Edit: AnthonyWJones pointed out that you're actually looking for the [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Operators/Special_Operators/this_Operator) operator.

> The *this* keyword refers to the context
>   object (a.k.a. current object). In
>   general, in a method, this refers to
>   the calling object.

Comment: Doesn't caller relate the the function that called the current function which is different from the object which called the function?

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a way to find a non-function element that called a function, you might consider using the event. This is a pretty handy function I use a lot when passed an event object.

```
function getTargetElement(evt) {
  evt = (evt) ? evt : ((window.event) ? window.event : "");
  var elem;
  if (evt.target) {
      elem = (evt.target.nodeType == 3) ? evt.target.parentNode : evt.target;
  } else {
      elem = evt.srcElement;
  }
  return elem;
}
```

So, for example, if you call a function "find(event);" from a clicked  element, find can be coded to use this method to get the event object:

```
function find(evt){
  var clickedObj = getTargetElement(evt);
  alert(clickedObj.tagName); //alerts "TD"
}
```